# Get Date Order Pattern For Cultures .NET

Tags: .net, globalization

Is there a property that gives a date order pattern for any culture in .NET?

For example: US - MDY, UK - DMY.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [DateTimeFormatInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.shortdatepattern(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
// M/d/yyyy
CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US").DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern

// yyyy-MM-dd
CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("sv-SE").DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern
```

Comment: I read about that one but I was hoping for a direct property as I only need DMY, MDY etc.

Comment: `DMY` is not a valid C# date formatting string. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I want to use this in SQL :)

Comment: Why would you want to store culture specific dates in the DB? Can't you do the formatting in .NET? Hard to help without the actual reason.